# change inside tag values or node values of xml in wso2 esb using any script works on wso2 esb

Tags: xml, xslt, integration, wso2-esb

This is My Source XML

```
<request>
<applicationVersion>agidmp-5.0.0.0</applicationVersion>
<serviceName>changeRequestService</serviceName>
<changes>
  <change>
    <entityName>ChangeRequest</entityName>
    <path>ChangeRequest--4</path>
    <operation>a</operation>
    <values>
      <changeRequestName>ChangeRequest-CR-007</changeRequestName>
      <changeRequestNumber>ChangeRequest-CR-007</changeRequestNumber>
      <changeRequestUID>ChangeRequest-CR-007</changeRequestUID>
      <productCategory>20984</productCategory>
      <requestCategory.recordId>20032</requestCategory.recordId>
      <sourceSystem.recordId>20048</sourceSystem.recordId>
      <scopeDescription> Minimum age limit:15Years</scopeDescription>
    </values>
  </change>
  <change>
    <entityName>ChangeRequestScopeCountry</entityName>
    <path>ChangeRequest--4.changeRequestCountryList--7</path>
    <operation>a</operation>
    <values>
      <country.recordId>IND</country.recordId>
    </values>
  </change>
  <change>
    <entityName>ChangeRequestScopeCountry</entityName>
    <path>ChangeRequest--4.changeRequestCountryList--8</path>
    <operation>a</operation>
    <values>
      <country.recordId>AFG</country.recordId>
    </values>
  </change>
  <change>
    <entityName>ChangeRequestScopeCountry</entityName>
    <path>ChangeRequest--4.changeRequestCountryList--9</path>
    <operation>a</operation>
    <values>
      <country.recordId>AUT</country.recordId>
    </values>
  </change>
  <change>
    <path>ChangeRequest--4.submissionRequestScopeStudyProgramList--5</path>
    <operation>a</operation>
    <entityName>SubmissionRequestScopeStudyAndProgram</entityName>
    <values>
      <invStudy.recordId>40037</invStudy.recordId>
    </values>
  </change>
</changes>
```

And i would like to replace the tag value in the following path :/soapenv:Body/request/changes/change/values/country.recordId

I tried with doing enrich mediator replace property. But it is not changing any tag values in my Source XML. Please suggest any methods to achieve this
My target xml should be Like

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <request>
    <applicationVersion>agidmp-5.0.0.0</applicationVersion>
    <serviceName>changeRequestService</serviceName>
    <changes>
      <change>
        <entityName>ChangeRequest</entityName>
        <path>ChangeRequest--4</path>
        <operation>a</operation>
        <values>
          <changeRequestName>ChangeRequest-CR-007</changeRequestName>
          <changeRequestNumber>ChangeRequest-CR-007</changeRequestNumber>
          <changeRequestUID>ChangeRequest-CR-007</changeRequestUID>
          <productCategory>20984</productCategory>
          <requestCategory.recordId>20032</requestCategory.recordId>
          <sourceSystem.recordId>20048</sourceSystem.recordId>
          <scopeDescription> Minimum age limit:15Years</scopeDescription>
        </values>
      </change>
      <change>
        <entityName>ChangeRequestScopeCountry</entityName>
        <path>ChangeRequest--4.changeRequestCountryList--7</path>
        <operation>a</operation>
        <values>
          <country.recordId>1234</country.recordId>
        </values>
      </change>
      <change>
        <entityName>ChangeRequestScopeCountry</entityName>
        <path>ChangeRequest--4.changeRequestCountryList--8</path>
        <operation>a</operation>
        <values>
          <country.recordId>1235</country.recordId>
        </values>
      </change>
      <change>
        <entityName>ChangeRequestScopeCountry</entityName>
        <path>ChangeRequest--4.changeRequestCountryList--9</path>
        <operation>a</operation>
        <values>
          <country.recordId>1236</country.recordId>
        </values>
      </change>
      <change>
        <path>ChangeRequest--4.submissionRequestScopeStudyProgramList--5</path>
        <operation>a</operation>
        <entityName>SubmissionRequestScopeStudyAndProgram</entityName>
        <values>
          <invStudy.recordId>40037</invStudy.recordId>
        </values>
      </change>
    </changes>
  </request>
</soapenv:Body>
```

is it possible to do this by adding some javascript code or using xQuery in wso2 mediators.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. There are several routes available. I was going to suggest to pass the recordId as a variable to an xslt but upon careful examination I see that you need to replace multiple 'recordId' elements for presumably different landcodes which is certainly not trivial.

In that case I'd suggest you use an xslt with a lookup table. As I haven't used one of those myself I was curious so I fiddled around with some examples and came up with the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://example.country"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<!-- copy everything that is not country.recordId -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- create a lookup variable based on the table at the bottom -->
<xsl:key name="id-lookup" match="s:id" use="s:abbr"/>
<xsl:variable name="allrecordids" select="document('')/*/s:recordIds"/>

<!-- replace the country.recordIds -->
<xsl:template match="country.recordId">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$allrecordids">
        <xsl:with-param name="curr-label" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="s:recordIds">
    <xsl:param name="curr-label"/>
    <country.recordId><xsl:value-of select="key('id-lookup', $curr-label)/s:nr"/></country.recordId>
</xsl:template>

<!-- the lookup table -->
<s:recordIds>
    <s:id><s:abbr>AFG</s:abbr><s:nr>1234</s:nr></s:id>
    <s:id><s:abbr>IND</s:abbr><s:nr>1235</s:nr></s:id>
</s:recordIds>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I made a big assumption here that the 'IND' and 'AFG' always results in the same number so hopefully this helps! At least it was fun :)

Comment: **Thank You So much** for the response but  'IND' and 'AFG' will change according to the System. Its like a DB Table which contains **table.Country_Name** as **IND** which is a _unique Key_ and i need the **table.ID** from that table which should get replace.

Comment: Is it possible to write a **Select Query** inside the XSLT ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to call a dblookup from within the xslt. Isn't it possible to add all the elements from the DB table to the xslt, assuming that this is a finite list that does not change very often?

Comment: Nope.it's not about one table. i need to make it  generic

Comment: Okay, I have some ideas, will try to post an update later today.

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated the solution above is not applicable to your specific use case, I came up with a different solution using foreach.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="translate_landcodes" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="http,https">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <foreach expression="//change">
                <sequence>
                    <filter xpath="//country.recordId">
                        <then>
                            <property expression="//country.recordId" name="landcode" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                            <sequence key="get_landnumber"/>
                            <enrich>
                                <source clone="true" property="landnumber" type="property"/>
                                <target xpath="//country.recordId"/>
                            </enrich>
                        </then>
                    </filter>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
    <description/>
</proxy>
```

I ran into the following bug https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-5227. Which is fixed in IE 6.20 and newer, but I solved it by moving the database call to a separate sequence:

```
<sequence name="get_landnumber" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <dblookup>
        <connection>
            <pool>
                <dsName>jdbc/landcodes_db</dsName>
            </pool>
        </connection>
        <statement>
            <sql><![CDATA[select numbercode from translate where lettercode=?]]></sql>
            <parameter expression="get-property('landcode')"
                type="VARCHAR" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
            <result column="numbercode" name="landnumber"/>
        </statement>
    </dblookup>
</sequence>
```

Note that you have to define the database connection in configuration/datasources.